# Is there a way to use multiple URLs for one Magento setup?

Tags: magento-1.7, url

I am planning to use Magento with multiple languages.

I was thinking of doing this:

English:

**Magento:** //website/store/[...](params for Magento)

French:

**Magento:** //website/magasin/[...](params for Magento)

I am using Apache server and I have access to the .htaccess file.

I am using Magento 1.7.

So is there a way for Magento to support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

1. first you need to create different stores in magento backend eg: magasin
2. Under each store create different storeviews corresponding to the language (similar to English, French and German storeviews in default magento installation).
3. Under System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Url options : set "Add Store Code to Urls" to "yes" (**but read the warning before u you do this**)
4. then create folders with the name you want for each language in your root directory (on server). "**magasin**" in your case
5. copy index.php and .htaccess to those folder (magasin)

in index.php (which is copied inside magasin folder)

replace

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
```

with

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'magasin';    // which was given in backend under store code
```

and replace

```
$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php';
```

and

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
```

with

```
$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '../includes/config.php';
```

and

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '../app/Mage.php';
```

respectively.

no changes in .htaccess needed.

in Admin panel again

> under System -> Configuration -> GENERAL -> Web -> Unsecure  section

(before editing, change the scope to magasin, which should be done under the Current Configuration Scope: on top left corner)

> change the base url to something like `http://website/magasin/`
>
> change the base skin url to something like `http://website/skin`
>
> change the base media url to something like `http://website/media`
>
> change the base js url to something like `http://website/js`

**under secure section:**

change only the base url to something like `http://website/magasin/` (do this only if all the above steps don't work)

**note:**

> remember the unsecure and secure urls should be changed under particular store configuration (scope) only, not under default scope.
>   if you want separate media and skin folder for this language copy them from root to magasin folder and give the relative path in unsecure section.

for having different urls for store views:

> Edit the urls under System -> Configuration -> GENERAL -> Web -> Unsecure section with store view selected as "Current Configuration Scope"
>
> eg: `http://website/magasin/french`, where french is the **store view code** you used while creating the store view.

for help, refer [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/)

Comment: Everything is under SSL. I have block anything that is not HTTPS to that website... Is that a good idea?

Comment: that's not a bad idea! But ensure your testing team go through the website and make sure that there's no prob. :)

Comment: Is there a way to do what you've written but for views not stores?

Comment: Because I am thinking of having stores for each country and use views for the languages.

Comment: yes it is possible, but i'll not be able to edit the answer now, I'll do it sooner when I find time to do it. :)

Comment: I've edited the answer, go through that once again :)

Comment: Actually, you don't have to create a folder per store, nor copy index.php and/or .htaccess files in it. Everything can be managed via Magento Admin, just assign a meaningful store code and let magento use "Store code in URLs" (Admin System > Config option).